# *ngFor with multiple image tags - how to know when all the image src are loaded

Tags: javascript, html, angular, ionic4

I have an array of image urls. On the HTML side, I show it in *ngFor tag.

Tech stack used - Ionic 4, angular 10

```
<div *ngFor="let url of imagesToLoad; let i = index">
            <ion-img [src]="url"></ion-img>
</div>
```

The imagesToLoad array can be shuffled and if the image is already loaded, then the url is not called again and hence the imageLoaded event is not fired.

I want to know if we can call a function once all the images are loaded.

please refer this link for stackblitz. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ynceyn?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Answer (score 1):

had a quick look into the docs: https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/img

it looks like the api exposes `ionImgDidLoad` event, so you could bind to that:

```html
<ion-img [src]="url" (ionImgDidLoad)="onImageLoaded()"></ion-img>
```

and then just count the calls:

```js
private loadCount = 0;
public onImageLoaded(): void {
   this.loadCount++;
   if(this.loadCount === this.imagesToLoad.length) {
       console.debug('All images loaded');
   }
}
```

Comment: I tried this approach. This fails when the images are shuffled and if an image is already loaded, then the event won't fire.. In that case this count mechanism fails.

Comment: i guess you need to reset the counter then, but i'm not sure, as i do not know when/how the library fires events

Comment: maybe it works in combination with the `ionImgWillLoad`? => i.e. increase imagesToLoad if ionImgWillLoad fires?

Comment: do you have a stackblitz for this shuffling behavior?

Comment: No. I don't have the shuffling logic. I will design a detailed stackblitz this weekend.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can fire a callback function in html.

What you can do is, make a GET request to the image.

let's say you get the response in B64 encoding. you can pass this data into the `src` attribute of the `img` tag like shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8499633/how-to-display-base64-images-in-html). In this way you can be sure that all the images are loaded before you inject into `img` tag.

you can also handle `onload` event on th `img`.
Eg:

```
var img = document.getElementsByClassName('img-class');
img.forEach(image => image.onload(function(e) {console.log("image loaded.")}));
```

This would call the onload function after each image loads. if you want to load once when all the images are loaded

i also see there is `ionImgDidLoad` event on ionic img. you can use that.